# Update ViewModel and View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

have a MainWindow where I navigate between UserControls by clicking on a menu and it works fine.

I am using this following pattern with Prism:

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/

After saving information I need to update a ViewModel, 
I update it but the View doesn't update. 
How can I fix it?

## **MainViewModel**

```
    public class AdminMenuViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
    {
        protected readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public AdminMenuViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) 
        { 
            PageViewModels.Add(new FoodSupplierViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new ProductViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new UnitViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new PriceViewModel());

            this._eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            this._eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateProduct>().Subscribe(UpdateProduct);

            // Set starting page
            CurrentUserControl = PageViewModels[0];
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        private List<IUserContentViewModel> _pageViewModels;
        public List<IUserContentViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pageViewModels == null)
                    _pageViewModels = new List<IUserContentViewModel>();

                return _pageViewModels;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateProduct()
        {
            PageViewModels[1] = new ProductViewModel(); //I update the ViewModel here
        }

        private void ChangeViewModel(IUserContentViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
                PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

            CurrentUserControl = PageViewModels
                .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
        }



        private ICommand _changePageCommand;

        public ICommand ChangePageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_changePageCommand == null)
                {
                    _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        p => ChangeViewModel((IUserContentViewModel)p),
                        p => p is IUserContentViewModel);
                }
                return _changePageCommand;
            }
        }
    }
```

## **MainView**

```
<UserControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type avm:FoodSupplierViewModel}">
            <av:FoodSupplierView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type avm:ProductViewModel}">
            <av:ProductView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type avm:UnitViewModel}">
            <av:UnitView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type avm:PriceViewModel}">
            <av:PriceView/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid  Margin="5" >
       <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10">
            <Grid>
                <Border Name="mask" Background="White" CornerRadius="9"/>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Height="58">
                        <MenuItem Header="General" FontSize="20" Height="38" Margin="10" Foreground="SteelBlue">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}" Width="168" >
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"  
                                                       CommandParameter="{Binding}" TextDecorations="{x:Null}">
                                                <InlineUIContainer>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="18"/>
                                                </InlineUIContainer>
                                            </Hyperlink>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </MenuItem>
                   </Menu>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8" >
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentUserControl}" Margin="0,0,-1,0"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` if you want to notify when there is an add/delete in that collection, use `OnPropertyChanged` if there is an update in an item